# Prometheus rule to fire an alert if the condition sustains for over a period of time

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I've this metric, at its working state or intended state looks like below (both are acceptable state)

```
 1. flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="", region="EMEA"} 40.0  
 2. flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="arrived", region="US"} 10.0
```

I wanted to kick off an alert when this metric
having label - `status` changes to `transit` and continues to be in the same state for more than an hour `flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="transit" ,region="US"} 20.0`

I can think of something like this - `increase(flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="transit"}[1h]) > 50` .
Would like to hear whether this is the right approach or can it be done better ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alert rule with expression returning all transit metrics, and `for` field set to one hour.

```yaml
  - alert: TransitTakesTooLong
    expr: flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="transit"}
    for: 1h
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: Transit takes more than 1h to finish
```

This will create alert, if metrics is returned for one hour by said query.

Comment: appreciate the input here . Ideally, when can be increase() or rate() used ?
i'm under assumption, since the counter always grows, it makes sense to use the `increase()` function.

Comment: @RafaS, this functions are used to calculate changes of metric's value. Based on your question, I don't see how value is related to alert creation, so this functions have nothing to do with situation.